# Upgrading SQL CE 3.5 to SQL Express Local DB with SyncFramework support?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, localdb

We are currently using ***`SQL CE 3.5`*** with many different bidirectional sync dbs (**Syncframework 2.1**) with server DBs, and `.net 4.5` windows based `WPF` application. But down the line the performance of the application degrades and we regularly need to regenerate the new local `SDF` for users. And by that way we see there is visible improvement in performance and after 60 days or so, the same happens. So we are looking for upgrading the *SQL CE*, but on research, we noticed that *SQL CE* **doesn't support SyncFramework**.

This raises the following questions:

- What is the best option to upgrade `SQL CE 3.5` **with Sync**?
- Will *SQL Local DB* support **SyncFramework 2.1**, if so, what are the things we need to take care, while upgrading to *SQL Local DB*?
- Does *SQL Local DB* support **Password Protection** and **Local Encryption**?

Moreover, [we read here](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html) that there is difference between Single (*SQL Compact CE*) and Multiple files (*SQL Local DB*).

- How do we handle the connections?

Comment: The question of local encryption & protection of the LocalDB database file has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097557/client-side-data-encryption-sql-server-express-localdb. In short - there is none.